# Adding input dynamically, jquery become not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I've been searching all over, and actually have found some of similar problem, but still can't manage to solve my problem. I'm still struggling learning jquery and still new.

Anywa, I'm trying to add dynamically an input on a table. So far, I've been able to show the adding of row with the new input text. The input text suppose to have autocomplete function. But the new dynamically added input never succeed to show the autocomplete options.

**(To make it clear, I put down the code into JSFiddle, here's the link:**

http://jsfiddle.net/yodann/6t74T/637/ )

Here is my code:

```
<?php
                            echo '<tr class="row_odd"><td class="ui-widget">';
                            echo form_input(array('id' => 'aff[]', 'name' => 'aff', 'value' => '',
                                    'class' => 'form-control auto_form', 'placeholder' => 'Masukkan nama tempat',
                                    'style' => 'width:100%'));
                            echo '</td><td><img src="'.getfrontendlink('images/del_button.png').
                                 '" width="24px" height="auto"></td></tr>';
?>

function addRow() {
    var count = $('#aff_table tr').length;
    var tx = count % 2 == 0 ? 'row_even' : 'row_odd';
    $('#aff_table tr:last').after('<tr class="' + tx + '">' +
        '<td class="ui-widget">'+
        '</td><td><img src="<?=getfrontendlink('images/del_button.png')?>" width="24px" height="auto"></td></tr>');

    var dat = $('#aff_table tr:last').children('td.ui-widget');
    $("input.auto_form:last").clone(true).appendTo(dat);
    $("input.auto_form:last").val("");           
}

<?php 
        if ($datas != '') {
            $i = 0;
            $php_array = array();
            foreach ($datas->result_array() as $row):
                $php_array[$i++] = ($row['pp_id'].'>>'.$row['pp_name'].', '.
                    (strlen($row['address']) > 25 ? substr($row['address'],0,25) : $row['address']).', '.
                    $row['city_name'].', '.$row['province_name']);
            endforeach;

            $js_array = json_encode($php_array);
            echo "var availableTags = ". $js_array . ";\n";
        }
?>

$( ".auto_form" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});
```

Comment: Hi, it seems like you are mixing Javascript and PHP code together. If that's the case, then your code wouldn't work.

If you are not doing willingly, then can you add a more precise code so I can help you debug it.

Comment: why so? because the initial input is working with fine. only the adding later on during runtime which never able to show the autocomplete option.

Comment: Hi Dubem, sorry to get u wrong. i've put up the code on jsfiddle. thank u. http://jsfiddle.net/yodann/6t74T/637/

Comment: I think your question is answered here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656589/using-jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-multiple-input-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I properly understood the problem: 
At the end of function addRow() you should init .autocomplete property again. 
If you instantiate auto-complete once, then after adding dynamic input field jquery does not automatically add the needed property.

```
function addRow() {
    var count = $('#aff_table tr').length;
    var tx = count % 2 == 0 ? 'row_even' : 'row_odd';
    $('#aff_table tr:last').after('<tr class="' + tx + '">' +
        '<td class="ui-widget">'+
        '</td><td><img src="<?=getfrontendlink('images/del_button.png')?>" width="24px" height="auto"></td></tr>');

    var dat = $('#aff_table tr:last').children('td.ui-widget');
    $("input.auto_form:last").clone(true).appendTo(dat);
    $("input.auto_form:last").val("");  

    $(".auto_form").autocomplete({source: availableTags});      
}
```

tried changing clone to simple append:
http://jsfiddle.net/rk27xbce/

Comment: no, it doesn't work. I did try this before, and no luck.

Comment: i tried playing with your jsfiddle, and main problem is with clone, because you get same atrributes (name and id), and jquery needs unique id to work properly.

Comment: TesiaMedia, thanks a lot for your help. I finnaly solved the issue. Two thing to note here, is to put inside document.ready(function) and like you said, the jquery needs a unique id. :)