# Get term for selected autocomplete when multiple are on one page

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a page where I am adding jquery-ui autocompletes dynamically

My .autocomplete() code includes a  $.getJSON('my_url', my_payload) where, in my_payload,' I am trying to send the *request.term* (what I typed into the jqueryui textbox) as well as the id of the jquery ui text box.

The problem is, for all the dynamically added textboxes, they were just picking up the term and id of the original autocomplete.

I managed to find a way to get the id of the added (not original) autocomplete by wrapping the autocomplete in a function that has the added field passed in as a parameter, but because the 'term' is in the request, which comes from .autocomplete, I do not know how to get this for the new ones.

https://jsfiddle.net/amchugh89/1L8jvea5/4/

```
//=======dynamic formset script from https://medium.com/all-about- 
django/adding-forms-dynamically-to-a-django-formset-375f1090c2b0======
function updateElementIndex(el, prefix, ndx) {
var id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+)');
var replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx;
if ($(el).attr("for")) $(el).attr("for", $(el).attr("for").replace(id_regex, replacement));
if (el.id) el.id = el.id.replace(id_regex, replacement);
if (el.name) el.name = el.name.replace(id_regex, replacement);
}
function cloneMore(selector, prefix) {
var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
var total = $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();

newElement.find(':input:not([type=button]):not([type=submit]):not([type=reset])').each(function() {

if ($(this).attr('name')){

    var name = $(this).attr('name').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
    var id = 'id_' + name;
    $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('').removeAttr('checked');

if($(this).attr('id').includes('gl')){

console.log($(this).attr('id'))
make_autocomplete($(this))

}


}
});
newElement.find('label').each(function() {
    var forValue = $(this).attr('for');
    if (forValue) {
      forValue = forValue.replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
      $(this).attr({'for': forValue});
    }
});
total++;
$('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
$(selector).after(newElement);
var conditionRow = $('.form-row:not(:last)');
conditionRow.find('.btn.add-form-row')
.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
.removeClass('add-form-row').addClass('remove-form-row')
.html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
return false;
}
function deleteForm(prefix, btn) {
var total = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
if (total > 1){
    btn.closest('.form-row').remove();
    var forms = $('.form-row');
    $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(forms.length);
    for (var i=0, formCount=forms.length; i<formCount; i++) {
        $(forms.get(i)).find(':input').each(function() {
            updateElementIndex(this, prefix, i);
        });
    }
}
return false;
}
$(document).on('click', '.add-form-row', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
cloneMore('.form-row:last', 'form');



return false;
});
$(document).on('click', '.remove-form-row', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
deleteForm('form', $(this));
return false;
});
//====================



//AUTOCOMPLETE==(that allows for multiple ACs 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656589/using-jquery-ui-autocomplete- 
with-multiple-input-fields)===================================

function make_autocomplete(ee) {

ee.on("focus", function(){    //.autocomplete({
  $(this).autocomplete({
  minLength: 2,
  source: function( request, response ) {
    var term = request.term;





   //with the formset, I want to get the row for which I am typing in the 
   'term'
    var this_formset_row_autocomplete_id 
    =ee.attr('id');//$(this.element).prop("id");//

$(this).attr('id');
    console.log(this_formset_row_autocomplete_id);


var corresponding_branch_html_id = 
this_formset_row_autocomplete_id.replace('gl_account','branch');
var this_formset_row_branch_sym_id = 
$('#'+corresponding_branch_html_id).val();
//console.log(corresponding_branch_html_id, this_formset_row_branch_sym_id)

var appended_data={term:term, 
this_formset_row_branch_sym_id:this_formset_row_branch_sym_id};

    console.log(appended_data);


    $.getJSON( "{% url 'dashapp:account_autocomplete' %}", appended_data, 
function( data,
status, xhr ) {
      //cache[ term ] = data;

      response( data );
    });
  }
});
 });

}//end function make_autocomplete

var ee =$( ".account_autocomplete" )
make_autocomplete(ee)

//===============
```

Comment: Curious about `var original_form_branch_id = $("#id_branch").val();` since `$("#id_branch")` does not appear to exist.

Comment: sorry, that is from when I had a form with just one autocomplete (I am switching to a formset)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to make it more simple for testing. Something like:

```
  function make_autocomplete(obj) {
    obj.autocomplete({
      minLength: 2,
      source: function(req, resp) {
        var myData = {
          term: req.term,
          original_form_branch_id: $(this).closest("form").attr("id"),
          this_formset_row_branch_sym_id: $(this).closest(".row").find("select").val()
        }
        $.getJSON("myurl", myData, function(results) {
          resp(results);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pywb9nhv/23/

This uses `.closest()` to gather details from the relative objects. Also I do not see any benefit to initializing Autocomplete on `focus` event.

If you would like further help, please provide Example Data that can be used in a working example.

Hope that helps a little.